# Choosing specific mode of publicTransport in HERE Routing API

Tags: here-api

In this link:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-routing-mode.html

One of the mode is publicTransport.
Is there a way to further classify publicTransport as "Bus", "Train"(for ex: if user wants to take only "BART" or "Metro" i.e. a Train instead of a Bus OR if the user wants to take only a Bus instead of a Train)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Routing Service does not support this deeper level. Therefore you can use the [Traffic API.](https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/topics/what-is.html)
The transit modes allow you to specify various types of vehicles that
you wish to be included in the transit routing results:

- High-speed trains
- Intercity/EuroCity trains
- Inter regional and fast trains
- Regional and other trains
- City trains
- Buses
- Boats/Ferries
- Metros/Subways
- Trams
- Ordered services/Taxis
- Inclined/Funiculars
- Aerials/Cable Cars
- Rapid Buses
- Monorails
- Airplanes

Comment: The response while using the route api(https://transit.api.here.com/v3/route.json?) has a duration value given as "duration "PT02H05M"". Whats the significance of "PT"?

Comment: The TimeDelta represents a fixed point in time from a start date or a duration. The format follow the ISO 8601 specification for durations.

Format: -?P(\d+Y)?(\d+M)?(\d+D)?T((\d+H)?(\d+M)?(\d+S)?)?                        You will find here further details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations